# TypeInitializationException when running Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP 3.8 example in c#

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp

I realize this issue was observed and resolved with the inclusion of the
props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");
However, the error persists.  I added corenlp 3.8 via nuget, I am using c# visual studio 2017, in a NetStandard2.0 configuration.

My code:
 `

```
public Dictionary<int, List<Word>> GetPOSFromStandforNLP(string sent)
        {
            var pos = new Dictionary<int, List<Word>>();
            var jarRoot = @"../vendor/stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models";

            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = new Properties();
            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");

            try
            {
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

                var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);   
                var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);
                // Annotation
                var annotation = new Annotation(text);
                pipeline.annotate(annotation);
                // Result - Pretty Print
                using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
                {
                    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
                    Console.WriteLine(stream.toString());
                    stream.close();
                }
```

`The error:`

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.Redwood' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.     at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.LoadCustomClassLoaderRedirects()    at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.GetCustomClassLoaderType()    at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.GetJavaClassLoader()    at java.lang.Class.getClassLoader(CallerID )    at java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus()    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.Redwood..cctor(
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to System.Configuration? That's what it says it's missing.

Comment: Agreed. But before I begin that investigation, but I wanted to be certain I wasn't missing something more obvious. -See post below

Answer (score 5):

[Stanford.NLP.NET](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET) is an [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/) project. IKVM is a [now defunkt](http://weblog.ikvm.net/default.aspx?month=2017-04) Java virtual machine implementation in .NET. It is does not support .NET Standard 2.0, only .NET Framework and Mono.

So your options are:

1. Target .NET Framework or Mono.
2. Port the [Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP Java project](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP) to .NET Standard.
3. Port the IKVM.NET project to .NET Standard (and preferably open source it so others who need a quick path to running Java code in .NET Standard can do so). Note that there is currently an effort underway called [ikvm-revived](https://github.com/ikvm-revived/ikvm).
4. Call Java using Pinvoke and a plain C-wrapper as a go-between that uses JNI to load the JVM and to expose functions that call into Java using JNI, as [described here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/766#issuecomment-317711332).
5. Implement your application in Java or [another language that Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP supports](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/).

Comment: Thank you!  You provided an excellent answer.  Based on your inputs, the expedient approach is to create proc and run coreNLP via cmd line.

Comment: Option #1 saved me a lot of time. Thanks!